# How to get value of checkbox that was generated client side

Tags: javascript, client-side, sitefinity

I have a form in Sitefinity and a custom field that when document ready, runs javascript that creates a checkbox client side. When the form is posted back, I would like to get the value of the client side generated checkbox but I can't seem to do it.

I have tried `httpcontext.current.request.form["myCheckbox"]` but it always returns a null value. I get the feeling Sitefinty works differently.

How do I go about getting the value of the client generated checkbox in Sitefinity after submit is clicked?

Comment: Can you post example markup?

Comment: myCheckbox would be the `name` attribute. Are you generating a checkbox with the attribute `name="myCheckbox"` ?

Comment: If you have custom field why would you be generating check boxes with JavaScript?